# Why won't my Ruby for-loop iterate over a String in my palindrome method?

Tags: ruby, string, for-loop, equality, palindrome

I am having trouble with getting my for-loop to process a string. It's just a simple method to tell whether or not a word is a palindrome (a word that is spelled that same way backwards and forwards). I have tweaked the for-loop multiple times but keep getting the same error message below. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

**Code:**

```
def palindrome?(string)

    string2 = ""

    for i in string
        string2 = string[i] + string2
    end 

    if string2 == string1
        return true 
    end 
end

palindrome?("abcba")
```

**Error:**

```
hours.rb:7:in `palindrome?': undefined method `each' for 5:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
    from hours.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! Very helpful!

Comment: Do you consider "Noon" (as opposed to "noon") to be a palindrome"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Generically, [the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Sentences_and_phrases) should be "yes," in which case one should use #downcase for the  comparison. But it's not really central to the problem the OP is facing, which is **the exception raised by his for-loop.** Sometimes solving for edge cases detracts from the main point, which is why I didn't include this topic in my answer. However, the use case you described is certainly a valid one to consider in a production-quality application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're looking for is:

```
def palindrome?(string)

  string2 = ""

  for i in 0...string.length
    string2 = string[i] + string2
  end

  if string2 == string
    return true
  end
end
```

Note you could define it simpler:

```
def palindrome?(string)
  string == string.reverse
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: @BrandonHill actually Carpetsmoker's answer is way more complete, and if you're interested in checking long strings you might want to do it by only looping over the string once, checking the first letter with the last, second with second-last etc. note also that in ruby you don't have to use return unless you want to break the control flow, as it's applicative language and the value of the last expression in function is it's return value anyway. good luck learning ruby!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you can't iterate over a string (like you can for example in Python). You'll first need to convert it to an Array with `.split`:

```
for c in string.split
    string2 = c + string2
end
```

That being said, you shouldn't use `for` loops in Ruby. They're translated internally to an `each` method, hence your confusing error. It's better to just write `each` from the get-go:

```
string.split.each do |c|
    string2 = c + string2
end
```

No Ruby programmer would ever use `for` in any circumstance, it's only used by people new to Ruby ;-)

---

Note that the [`Array.each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) is just *one* iteration method; for example there's also the [`String.each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) method:

```
string.each_char do |c|
    string2 = c + string2
end
```

---

Lastly, your code is not correct in several other locations. I'm not going to point out all these errors to you, as it will be much more beneficial and educational for you if you solve this programming exercise yourself ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I am new to Ruby and coding in general so I have much to learn.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

Aside from being inefficient, your code doesn't work because a [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) is not an [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html), nor does it mix in [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html) to provide an #each method.

While the [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method allows indexing into the string, there is no String#each method to invoke. As a result, you can't use a String object in a Ruby for-loop because it's just syntactic sugar for #each.

### Understanding the Exception

I'm not sure what version of Ruby you're running, but the exception you've listed in your post is not reproducible on my system. When running on Ruby 2.3.1, the code generates a fairly clear exception:

```
for i in string
    string2 = string[i] + string2
end
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "abcba":String

This is pretty straighforward. It tells you that String has no #each method, which is what the syntactic sugar of `for i in string` is really invoking under the hood. If you want to iterate, you need some form of [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html) or [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumeraable.html) to work with.

### Iterating Over a String

The String class has a number of useful methods for converting a string to an iterable object. Some examples include:

- [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_char) can be passed a block, or return an Enumerator
- [String#chars](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chars) returns an Array
- [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) also returns an Array (e.g. `'abcba'.split //`)

For example, your code could be refactored to use a block like so:

```
string = 'abcba'
tmpstr = ''
string.each_char { |char| tmpstr < char; puts true if tmpstr == 'abcba' }
#=> "abcba"
```

However, while this highlights how to solve for your exception, it is still needlessly complex and inefficient.

### Leveraging Built-In Methods

Unless you're doing this for homework, the right way to do this in Ruby is to leverage the built-in methods that operate at C speeds and don't create temporary Ruby objects that need to be garbage-collected later. For example, to test whether a given string reads the same backwards or forwards, you can simply compare a reversed string to the original using the [String#reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-reverse) and [String#eql?](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-eql-3F) methods.

```
def palindrome? str
  str.reverse.eql? str
end

palindrome? 'abcba'
#=> true

palindrome? 'abcde'
#=> false
```

You can also use [String#==](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) instead of `#eql?` if you prefer, but I think using the latter is clearer in this case. The method chain makes it clear that you're invoking a String method rather than a bit of language syntax for the comparison. That distinction can be a real help when learning the ins and outs of Ruby's core, but in this case the result will be the same either way.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. Very helpful!

Comment: @BrandonHill Welcome to Stack Overflow. No thanks are necessary. The right way to show your appreciation on Stack Exchange is to upvote the answers you found useful (you can upvote more than one answer if you like), and to hit the checkmark to accept whichever answer helped you most.

Answer (score 2):

As Carpetsmoker pointed out, you can't iterate directly over a string.  However, Ruby provides both positive and negative indexing for elements.  Negative indices are located relative to the end of the array or string.  This allows you to do your checking quite efficiently, and short circuit your testing as soon as you identify you don't have a palindrome:

```
def palindrome?(str)
  (0...str.length/2).all? { |i| str[i] == str[-(i+1)] }
end
```

If you want to be more object-oriented about it, you can convert it to a method in class String:

```
class String
  def palindrome?
    (0...length/2).all? { |i| self[i] == self[-(i+1)] }
  end
end

p "abcba".palindrome?  # => true
```

---

**Note** — Edited to utilize Cary Swoveland's excellent suggestion about using `all?` rather than an explicit return from the block.  This makes it a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
def palindrome?(str)
  str == str.reverse
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!